# Redirect URL with value from Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, controller

I'm new to Laravel and am stuck with an issue for a few days. I did this with my PHP code...

```
<a class="btn_full" href="/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=<?php echo $distance_km; ?>">Place Order</a>
```

I want to use an HREF in a Laravel controller to do the same thing...

**Update 2**

```
<?php

public function custom_pay(Request $request)
{
    try {
        Stripe::setApiKey(Setting::get('stripe_secret_key'));
        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
            'source' => $token,
            'email' => Auth::user()->email,
        ]);
        request('distance');

        return redirect('/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=' . $distance);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

However, it's not sending the `$distance_km` value with the URL. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

**Update 3**

I added this part as suggested...

```
$distance= request('distance');

return redirect('/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=' . $distance);
```

Inside the blade file, I added this:

```
<input name="distance" value="{{ $distance_km }}" type="hidden" />
```

It still doesn't work. It's generating this URL: "mysitename.com/createorder?placed=true" and doing everything else other than saving the distance value. In the database, the value is empty which was supposed to be passed via URL.

Comment: `$distance = request('distance');` is missing.. you are not storing the value anywhere

Comment: It still doesn't work It is generating this URL: "mysitename.com/createorder?placed=true" and doing everything else other than saving distance value. In the database, the value is empty which was supposed to be passed via URL. @nakov

Comment: have you tried printing out request()->all() to ensure what you are passing through to the controller? Did you put your input within the form, or just elsewhere in the blade view?

Comment: The issue is the distance variable is created outside any form on a View body inside a PHP tag. That's the problem I think as it's not a part of post method. The value was passed via URL before from the body. Is there a way to it inside a controller from the View file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation is used with double quotes in PHP like this

```
return redirect("/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=$distance_km");
```

or you can concatenate your value like this:

```
return redirect('/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=' . $distance_km);
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work. 
Part of the problem I think is that the controller doesn't know the value of $distance_km which is coming from a .blade.php file. How do I pass the value of $distance_km from the blade file to the controller?

Comment: use `request('distance_km');` or try `dd(request()->all())` in the controller to check what values are you sending to the controller.

Comment: I see now that your param is `distance` so use `request('distance');`

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't work. Sorry I don't understand lot of things. So the cotroller still doesn't get the value. Should I pass the through the route to the controller or the controller should get the value directly from the view file?

Comment: do you at all get into the controller action? can you print anything in it? Once you click on the link, can you give me the generated URL?

Comment: Here is the thing. This controller is used to send generated token to the stripe server. At the end of the controller I want to call "place-order.php" file as it saves all my cart items to the database. It works. 
But I also need to add  $distance_km with the URL as it saves the distance to the database. If I remove the '&distance=$distance_km' part, It saves all the data but the distance. 
Previously the URL was called via an anchor tag within the blade file and it was working perfectly.

Comment: Previously the URL was called using an anchor tag within the blade file . Now I want to call the function from the controller and call the URL from the controller. The route doesn't pass any parameter though. Should I change anything there? All I understand my controller doesn't know the value of $distance variable so It can't pass it.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your flow, but if you are generating the stripe token within the same action in your controller, then before that in the view you can use a hidden field: `<input name="distance" value="{{$distance_km}}" />` and use its value as I said above from the request object.

Comment: Just tried that. It doesn't work. It reloads and stays at the same page. Doesn't go to the new URL. If I remove '&distance=$distance_km' from the url, it goes to the new URL and saves everything other than the distance value. I don't know what else to try. 
Thank you for your kind support though. Learned a lot of new things.

Comment: if you can share more code, than it will be easier to help.

Comment: `code`public function custom_pay(Request $request){
    try{
            Stripe::setApiKey(Setting::get('stripe_secret_key'));
            $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'source' => $token,
    'email' => Auth::user()->email,    ]);
    
    request('distance');
    return redirect('/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=' . $distance);
    }
}
`code`

Comment: You are not storing the value of `request('distance')` to a `$distance` variable. So try replacing your last line with this:

`return redirect('/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=' . request('distance'));`

Comment: It still doesn;t work  It is generating this url: 
"https://mysitename.com/createorder?placed=true" and doing everything else other than saving distance value. In database the value is empty which was supposed to be passed via URL. I have also created the <input > tag that you suggested in blade and it gives correct value, but the contoller can't get the value for some reason. This is my Route for the controller: 
Route::post('/customPay', 'PaymentController@custom_pay');

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Laravel structure, you could not use the core php.

```
return redirect->route('your routename');
```

Answer (score 0):

look docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

and here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#urls

do this like:
`return redirect("/place-order.php?placeorder=true&distance=$distance_km");`